# More than Three vertical button in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The built in android AlertDialog.Builder has maximum three button options(positive,negative,neutral) and they are aligned horizontally. I want to add more buttons to it, and set the orientation Vertically.

How can I do it ?

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create your customise Dialog.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.class);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
dialog.setTitle("Dialog message");
```

And now you can simple create new xml file and put there whatever you want.

Manage the buttons:

```
Button close = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
          dialog.cancel();
    }   
});
```

Check on:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

use `Android.app.Dialog` instead. There is no helper builder class, however.

[Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom layout.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Create your own layout and Inflate it to get the View and follow the link for the rest.